# How to check if a certain object ID is a page or post (from outside of the page/post itself)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a navigation menu loop that uses a custom walker which outputs:

```
<ul>
<li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item-object-category">stuff</li>
<li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item-object-category">stuff</li>
...
etc
And if a page is in the menu, it outputs:
<li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item-object-page">stuff</li>
</ul>
```

Clearly wordpress somewhere detects that the entry in the menu is either a category or a page and assigns the appropriate class. How can I run that same check in my walker?

I simply want to do an

```
If ($item->object_id = page) { // special code}
```

I tried is_page(), but realized that that is a boolean function to detect if the current page you are on is a page or not.

Is there any easy way of checking each output in a walker for pages?

This is my walker code:

```
class Custom_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{ 
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;

        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;

                $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;

        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) function and check the type, for example:

```
<?php

$current_post = get_post($current_post_id);
if ($current_post->type == 'post') {
  //Do the stuff with post
}
elseif ($current_post->type == 'page') {
  //Do the stuff with page
}
else {
  //Do the stuff with other post types
}
```

Comment: It needs to be if ($current_post->post_type == 'page') but other than that it is exactly what I needed thank you!